# VS Code Error spawning PHP: Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am not sure what do to.
I have installed VS Code and keep getting this when I start it:

```
Error spawning PHP: Command failed with exit code 1: C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.2-Win32-vs16-x64 --version 'C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.2-Win32-vs16-x64' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

This is my setting file:

```
{
    "editor.fontSize": 18,
    "blade.format.enable": true,
    "phpformatter.composer": true,
    "[php]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "kokororin.vscode-phpfmt"
    },
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\laragon\\bin\\php\\php-8.1.2-Win32-vs16-x64",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Atom One Dark",
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 16,
    "markdown.preview.fontSize": 21,
    "debug.console.fontSize": 21,
    "editor.suggestFontSize": 21,
    "editor.fontWeight": "300",
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": null,
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[vue]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur"
    },
    "[css]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
    "bracketPairColorizer.depreciation-notice": false,
    "phpcs.executablePath": "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Composer\\vendor\\bin\\phpcs.bat",
    "phpcs.enable": false,
    "phpcs.showWarnings": false,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "window.zoomLevel": 2,
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "php.executablePath": "C:\\laragon\\bin\\php\\php-8.1.2-Win32-vs16-x64",
    "php.debug.executablePath": ""
}
```

This path is 100% right C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.2-Win32-vs16-x64

Any idea what is happening please?

Thanks!